# reference vue instance in mapState function

Tags: vuejs2

Is there a way in Vue2 to do this:

```js
....,
computed {
  ...mapState('myModule', {
    myVal: (state, vm) => state.someVar.filter((_) => { return vm.someVar })
  })
},
....
```

The actual function I'm working on is filtering the `state.someVar` in a more complex scenerio, so this is simplified.  The point being that `this` is undefined.

Anyone know how to reference the vue in such a function?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument to the mapState function is supposed to be a state mapper (array or object)
If you are using an object (as you are), you can only set the properties of the object to the keys in your "myModule" state object. You cannot set them as functions

e.g  {customName: moduleStateKey}

As for passing component instance, you can only do that in an action or mutation. However, that would make your store impure. It would be better to pass someVar to state via a mutation fired from the component, then use a getter for the filter logic and use the someVar passed to state there

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the code.  There is nothing in my example that is mutating the state.  Though I am missing a parenthesis in my example, which I will fix.  But the example code will work aside from the `vm` argument which I added to show what I wanted to do.

Comment: ok, since you are using an array method, try passing "this" to the thisArg (2nd argument of the filter method). I'm surprised your code even works, to be honest